# Reports Metadata using Apex

Tags: apex, metadata

I need to get the metadata of the reports using apex in jason or XML format.
Can anyone help me to achieve this without using metadata api.

Thanks

Comment: why is metadata API not an option?

Comment: Metadata API is huge to use & my senior developer asked to try another option.
Is there any other way we can do it.
I'm try to replicate as similar to ant, as in ant we provide the XML & we get the entire metadata.